# Configuring Selenium WebDriverTests using app.config

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, app-config

I have a test-project which performs WebDriverTests.

At this moment I have the following in my code:

```
private readonly string url = @"http://localhost:3000/#/search/persons";
```

My application (including the webdrivertests) is deployed using TeamCity (installed on PC-A) and deploys the application to PC-B.

When the deployment is done, I want to run my webdrivertests on PC-B as part of the TeamCity-deployment. But with the above mentionned line this doesn't work since the application isn't deployed on the server where my TeamCity is running.

Is there a way to do this using an app.config?
Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Richard Bradshaw (@FriendlyTester on Twitter) has a great approach to handle this. I use the same approach, Richard just has an [existing great blogpost](http://www.thefriendlytester.co.uk/2014/02/webdriver-factory.html) I can point you to.

Comment: Ok, i can add my app.config but then how can I transform it when it is deployed?